# perl loop avoid print duplicate in regex match

Tags: regex, perl, loops, foreach, while-loop

I Search, and research for a solution but without successful.

The file.txt:

```
Name Server: NS1.SERVER.COM
Name Server: NS2.SERVER.COM
..........................
..........................
Name Server: NS1.SERVER.COM
Name Server: NS2.SERVER.COM
Whois server: whois.directnic.com!
..........................
..........................
Name Server: NS1.SERVER.COM
Name Server: NS2.SERVER.COM
Whois server: whois.directnic.com!
..........................
..........................
```

When I run:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'file.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
      if ($row =~ /^Name\sServer:\s+(.*+)?/) {          
          print "dns $1\n";
      }

      if ($row =~ /Whois.+server:.(.*)/) {
          print "whois server: $1\n";
      }
}
```

The output:

```
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
whois server: whois.directnic.com!
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
whois server: whois.directnic.com!
```

I want to get like this:

```
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
whois server: whois.directnic.com!
```

I know I can use Last
**(If you’ve used the “break” operator in C or a similar language, it’s like that.)**

If I set last; in the first condition I get this:

```
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
```

If I set last; in the second condition I get this:

```
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
dns NS1.SERVER.COM
dns NS2.SERVER.COM
whois server: whois.directnic.com!
```

I find a solution but using hash, while, increase count and grep, like this:

```
my %count_of; 
my %count_of_two; 
while (my $row = <$fh>) {

          if ($row =~ /^Name\sServer:\s+(.*+)?$/) {

              $count_of{$row}++; 

            }

           if ($row =~ /Whois.+Server:.(.*)/) {

              $count_of_two{$row}++; 
          }

    }
    print join "\n", grep { $count_of{$_} > 1 } keys %count_of; 
    print join "\n", grep { $count_of_two{$_} == 1 } keys %count_of_two;
```

¿How can I do this with while or foreach?

Note: I think I know why while loop print duplicate because that the functionality, but maybe exist another way.

I research about this but I can't find a solution.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Why not print repeated lines once: `perl -ne '!/^\.+$/g && print unless $w{$_}++' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to use a hash (called `%seen` in my example below) which keeps track of the strings you have ever seen.

Making the smallest changes to your code, we get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'file.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my %seen;

while (my $row = <$fh>) {
      if ($row =~ /^Name\sServer:\s+(.*+)?/) {
          print "dns $1\n" unless $seen{$1}++;
      }

      if ($row =~ /Whois.+server:.(.*)/) {
          print "whois server: $1\n" unless $seen{$1}++;
      }
}
```

Comment: Good. But do you understand it, or are you just copying blindly from the internet?

Comment: Hi @Dave Cross, sorry for the delay. I understand a little about the code. Can you please tellme ¿how can I set a counter?  like: count 1 count 2 count 3... for just the match that are not duplicate. I set a count but it count like  1,2,3,4,5...(it count the duplicate match)

Comment: @Thenothing: If you have a new question, then it's best to ask it as a completely new question.

Comment: Thanks, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390249/perl-set-counter-to-match-in-loop