# Perl set counter to match in loop

Tags: perl, loops, counter

How can I set a `$counter++` to hash unless is `1`? in this code:

```
use strict;
    use warnings;    

    my @filestwo = glob("*.xml");
    my $result = @filestwo;          

    my $count = 0;
    my %justone;
    foreach my $domain (@filestwo) {
      open my $in, '<', $domain or die "Open fail on $domain $!\n";
        my @linestwo = <$in>;        

            for my $line (@linestwo) {

                if($line =~ /Domain:\s([a-z].+)/){
                  $count++;
                  print "Number:$count Your TLD $1!\n" unless $justone{$1}++;
                }                

            }

}
```

The output:

```
Number:1 Your TLD one.com!
Number:3 Your TLD three.com!
Number:5 Your TLD two.com!
```

Should be:

```
Number:1 Your TLD one.com!
Number:2 Your TLD three.com!
Number:3 Your TLD two.com!
```

Explanation about the code:

- Open 3 files `.xml` (In every file exist duplicate pattern)
- Create a hash `%justone;`
- Search from the array if the match the pattern: domain
- If match and in the next iteration match again the same pattern, just print 1 with `unless $justone{$1}++;`

My problem, I can't set a counter just for the match relation unless hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to increment unless some condition is met,
you should mention that in your code.

Using the postfix `foo() unless condition();` syntax means the condition will only refer to the previous statement, not the entire scope ( which would arguably be insane to parse ).

So `print '...' unless $foo` is the same as `unless( $foo ){ print '...'; }`.

Thus, if you want to include more than one statement in your unless condition, you need to use curly braces: `unless ( $foo ) { # as many lines as desired }`

If I understood your question correctly, you want to do:

```
unless ( $justone{$1}++ ){
    $count++;
    print "Number:$count Your TLD $1!\n"
}
```

This will increment only if the condition was met, and lead to the desired output. I would suggest to use a named variable for what you've captured in $1 to make it more readable, though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$count++` should only be done once per domain like the `print`, which means you could simply move `$count++` into the `unless`'s body.

Alternatively, you could simplify your code by using

```
my %seen;
my @uniq_domains =
   grep !$seen{$_}++,
      map /Domain:\s([a-z].+)/,
         <$in>;
```

or

```
use List::Util qw( uniq );

my @uniq_domains =
   uniq
      map /Domain:\s([a-z].+)/,
         <$in>;
```

Then, the following outputs what you want:

```
say sprintf "%d. %s", $_+1, $uniq_domains[$_]
   for 0..$#uniq_domains;
```